# Unable to get entire string value to POST or GET to search bar only first word will apear

Tags: php, html

So, I have created a dynamic list of links from an sql query. this all works fine, however when the link is clicked I want to pass the string value of the link through a Get/Post variable into a search bar. 
I can get this all to work but for some reason only the first word of the string value is being sent. for example a link "This is the Link" once clicked will only pass "This" to the search bar. I have looked around and have a feeling it has something to do with with the ' " positions.

```
$num=1;
                if( $row_cnt = $print->num_rows >= 1 ) {
                    while( $arr = $print->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                        print( "<tr>\r\n" );
                        foreach( $arr as $key=>$value) {
                            /*These statements ensure author is printed on one line*/
                            if($num == 1)
                            {

                            print( "<td><a href =".$rootPath."search/master_page_search.php?key='".$value."' >".$value."</a> </td>\r\n" );
                            $num=2;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                print( "</br><td><a href =".$rootPath."search/master_page_search.php?key=".$value." >".$value."</a><br/> </td>\r\n" );/*---These are the lines the value is being sent from It is printed correctly but $value only sends the first word in the $GET_['key']*/
                            $num=1;
                            }

                        }

                        print( "</tr>\r\n " );
```

The PHP then puts the value into the search bar by placing the $_GET['key] into the search bars value.

```
if(isset($_GET['key']))
{
    echo $_GET["key"];
}
```

The links display correctly with the entire string however the value only contains a single word value...

Comment: can you show how your link looks

Comment: try to `urlencode` the value in the href

Comment: Yes! that was it thank you so much for the quick easy fix! you guys are awesome!  
print( "<td><a href =".$rootPath."search/master_page_search.php?key=".urlencode($value)." >".$value."</a> </td>\r\n" );

Answer (score 0):

Another way of making it works is to surround the $value between '' and "" ej:

```
echo "<option value=" . "'$row[1]'" . ">" . $row[1] . "</option>";

                              OR

echo '<option value=' . "'$row[1]'" . '>' . $row[1] . '</option>';
```

This line is showing inside the selector the String, for example, "Hello World" and
sending "'$row[1]'", note the double pair of "''", in both cases are the same.